# How to iterate through Graph data from an SPFx web part?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, spfx

Sorry for the dumb question!

In my code below I get all the members of a M365 group and they display in the console.log.

However I don't know how to iterate through the JSON that is returned.

Thanks
P

```
    const theADUsers: any = await client.api(`/groups/${GUID}/members/microsoft.graph.user`)
      .header('ConsistencyLevel', 'eventual')
      //.search('displayName:P')
      .select('displayName,id,mail,surname')
      //.orderby('displayName')
      .get();

      console.log('theADUsers...');
      console.log(theADUsers);



{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,id,mail,surname)",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "Doe, John",
            "id": "GUID",
            "mail": "John.Doe@somewhere.com",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Doe, John",
            "id": "GUID",
            "mail": "John.Doe2@somewhere.com",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Doe, John",
            "id": "GUID",
            "mail": "John.Doe3@somewhere.com",
            "surname": "Doe"
        },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
theADUsers.value.forEach(user => console.log(user));
```

The result should be already parsed and you do not need JSON parsing. For reference look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph

Comment: If I try that I get an error. var client = await this.context.msGraphClientFactory.getClient('3');
    var result = await client.api('groups/9cc93f8e-4798-4902-9e20-5e31d677a653/members').get();
    //do something with the result here
      console.log(result);

      result.value.forEach(user => console.log(user));


    }catch(e){
      
      stringToReturn = e.message.toString();

    }

Comment: Parameter 'user' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: That is not an error, it is more a warning from eslint? But yeah, you should create an interface for the user and have something like forEach((user: MicrosoftGraph.User) => console.log(user))

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the json. Here is an example https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).